# TypeError: $ is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, undefined

I have simple function, but when i call it, im getting **TypeError: $ is undefined**

Is there any error in the code?
Maybe its something wrong due to wordpress that im using ?

```
function dynamic_Select(fk, value)
 {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data:{
             fk:    fk,
             value: value,
         },
    success:function(response){ alert('success');   },
    error: function (request, status, error) { alert(request.responseText);   }

}); 


}
```

Im calling this function from:

```
  <select name="<?=$field['key']?>" onchange="dynamic_Select(this.getAttribute('name'), this.value)">
```

Comment: Where did you define `$`?

Comment: Jquery isn't ready at the time that function is run. There isn't enough code given to provide a full answer.

Comment: you mean fk and value ? 
`<select name="<?=$field['key']?>" onchange="dynamic_Select(this.getAttribute('name'), this.value)">`

Comment: usually a `noConflict` issue in wordpress